# Infinite Scroll in NodeJS and Mongoose App

Tags: node.js, ajax, express, mongoose, infinite-scroll

I have built an app using NodeJS, Express, and Mongoose. I have used EJS as the template engine. My MongoDB collection has over 1000 records and the app seems to be rendering them very slowly. I have used the infinite scroll concept in PHP but I was not able to implement it in Node. Could someone please help me implement an infinite scroll pattern so that the first few records from the database can be loaded quickly and other documents from the database are retrieved only if the user decides to scroll on the page?

I had used AJAX to implement infinite scroll in PHP, but I can't seem to understand how I should use the same in Node.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bucket pattern https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-1.

Comment: @RichardRublev, thank you for the reply. But I really could not understand how I would implement such a thing in mongoose using EJS. Could you please help me out?